# Android Studio cannot find com.android.tools.build:grade:2.10

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ionic-framework

Having resolved an error thanks to tihs ['Gradle Version 2.10 is required'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error) post. I'm not getting a new error.

I've been trying to follow answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157716/android-studio-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-0-0-alpha2) but nothing I try seems to work.  I wonder if this is because I'm on a later version of gradle and Android Studio.  I'm still getting this error in Android Studio

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
file:/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
Required by:
:android:unspecified
```

I've updated my `build.gradle` file to include:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10'
    }
}
```

And `gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

I'm at a loss of what to try next.  This is app build on the Ionic framework (using cordova).  the `ionic build android` command results in the same error too.

I'm using a Mac and Android Studio 2.1

Comment: Did you update android studio to 2 + version.

Comment: It's AndroidStudio 2.1.  I've moved computer, so this a new install.  Couldn't tell you from which version I've updated from.  But I'm trying to update an existing project

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I'm still getting the same error.  I tried changing the `distributionUrl` too, but that just gave a me a download error

Answer (score 1):

there is no version : `2.10` in `gradle` for `Android Studio` change it to:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
}
```

---

**new answer :**

please try to update `gradle-wrapper.properties` :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

then in project `build.gradle` use this version:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

From menu: choose File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart... >> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I'm still getting the same error.  I tried changing the `distributionUrl` too, but that just gave a me a download error

Comment: please try my new answer, i didn't payed attention that you are using  Ionic framework

Comment: If I lower the version I get a 'Gradle version 2.10 is required' error

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 2.x is not available in the maven repository, so you have to provide other repos to satisfy all your dependencies, in settings.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    jcenter()
}
```