# Cannot update Gradle for Android to 2.13.0 to use ProtoBuf

Tags: android, gradle, protocol-buffers

Hey I'm working on a project and I was trying to use the ProtoBuf Gradle Plugin. At first I was getting [this issue](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/75) because I currently have Gradle 2.10 installed so I followed the instructions here as well a

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157716/android-studio-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-0-0-alpha2), the Gradle files were moved to JCenter but when I followed the urls, I got a 404 response. I tried changing the distribution URL as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34749866/6421112) and then invalidating the cache and restarting but that didn't fix it either. In frustration I deleted the stuff in the .gradle folder (trying to clear the cache) but that didn't work either and I haven't been able to get them back.

I tried changing it to the default wrapper as an answer I can't find again suggested that didn't work. I tried downloading Gradle 2.13 on my own and placing it in the Android Studio directory but Windows 8 deleted it.

The only thing I can think of is that this is my first time actually putting Gradle to use on this computer and I don't have admin rights. Earlier in the session, I closed out of an Admin Password request for something to do with the Java SE. I don't know how to undo that. Any help would be appreciated.

Other answers I tried:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34179425/6421112 - Android Support Repository is installed fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34749866/6421112

The error I'm getting is listed bellow, I had to censor the url part from the urls.

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.13.0. Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13.0/gradle-2.13.0.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13.0/gradle-2.13.0.jar
%jcenter%/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13.0/gradle-2.13.0.pom
%jcenter%/android/tools/build/gradle/2.13.0/gradle-2.13.0.jar Required by:
:MyApplication:unspecified
```

Here's a stacktrace:

```
Required by:
    :BluetoothHeartbeat:unspecified
        at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:560)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:570)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:256)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:230)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolve(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:371)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:346)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:339)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:664)
        ... 53 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.89 secs
```

Here's my **build.gradle (MyApplication)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.13.0'

        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.7'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here's the other **build.gradle** (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//applyplugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.MyApplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: You did not change gradle version, you changed the android plugin version. Whats the difference? [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36040177/745574)

Comment: That didn't really help because I've already tried to change the distribution URL. The "Customizable gradle wrapper" wasn't an option as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this on my own. Turns out the Android Plugin version for this version is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2`. I set it to that and the latest version downloaded fine.