# Gradle Failed Sync

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

hi i get error for 2 day i test a lot of gradle version i test gradle 3.3.0 and 3.4.0 and change it a lot of time at gradle-warper.properties i change above line

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4-all.zip
```

my android studio version 2.3 last version with full update of sdk

now i got this error every time

error code of gradle 3.4.0

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
    https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
    https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

error code of gradle 3.3.0

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
    https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.pom
    https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.0/gradle-3.4.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

i check this location

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle
```

and nothing at there !

i need gradle 3.3 or gradle 3.4

thanks if have solution tell me

Comment: there is no `com.android.tools.build:gradle` 3.4 yet ... even alpha is only 2.5 ... so obviously problem is not with gradle itself but android tools

Comment: @Selvin how to get it ?

Comment: It's all in the documentation

Comment: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ shows latest gradle to be  gradle-3.5-rc-1-src.zip. In my andoid studio its distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip

Comment: i try try every thing but don't work

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007 i tried gradle-3.5-rc-1-src.zip but error occuerd

Comment: @Selvin i download gradle externally and then paste it but still error occuerd

Comment: Again, **it has nothing to do with gradle version** ... this error is because wrong version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` (inside build.gradle)

Comment: can this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157716/android-studio-could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle2-0-0-alpha2